# What are the pros and cons of determining a document type based on optional fields or a type flag?

Tags: mongodb

what are some of the pros and cons of determining the type of a document based on existence of certain fields vs having a type flag? is finding certain clothing types based on existence of certain fields less efficient than finding based on type?

ex:

### Clothes collection

```
{
  type: 'shirt'
  sleeveLength: 15
  color: 'red'
},

{
  type: 'pants'
  waist: 30
  color: 'black'
}
```

vs

```
{
  sleeveLength: 15
  color: 'red'
},

{
  waist: 30
  color: 'black'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first example

```
{
  type: 'shirt'
  sleeveLength: 15
  color: 'red'
},
```

is more flexible, as content could be easily predicted/assumed by its type and there is no need to make additional logic check for more sophisticated products as `sleeveLength` can be connected with shirt and jacket.

The second example

```
{
  sleeveLength: 15
  color: 'red'
},
```

need to have an extra fields/attributes and even if we can have a sparse index, query results could be not so precise (as sleeve could be in blouse, shirt, jacket...)

any comments welcome!